# AWS iOS SDK TLS Support

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Related Question:
[AWS S3 Disabling SSLv3 Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29656452/aws-s3-disabling-sslv3-support)

This is more of an inquiry for the mobile iOS SDK. Wondering what I have to do or where to start since am a bit clueless.

Also just received a notice that Amazon is deprecating SSLv3 and that I need to modify my requests to use TLS.

This is an older iOS app still using the AWS iOS SDK 1.7 version. This basically just accesses S3 Buckets for both upload and download of images.

Now is this normally handled already by the library or do I have to update to the v2 library, thereby dropping iOS 6 support. Or can it just be through code changes, etc.

Comment: I think is handled by iOS because I think You can't choose ssl or tls on your connections. Is done by the server

Answer (score 2):

The SSLSecurityLevel is handled by iOS.

[Apple's Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFSocketStreamRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/CFStream_Property_SSL_Settings_Constants) "By default, a stream’s security level is kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL. ", which means the client negotiated with server and choose the highest level security protocol agreed by both end.

Since all iOS version supports TLS,by default, iOS client will always try to use TLS during negotiation, and fallback to SSLv3 if it is not available. As long as server supports TLS, you should see no SSLv3 communications unless the default SSLSecurityLevel has been changed.